# Robust and native way to completely change from `C-x` to `C-S-x` in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, cua-mode

I am aware of `CUA` mode in emacs, i.e. using `Ctrl+x` for "cut".

I would like to ask what is the native and robust way to completely change the original `C-x` to `C-S-x`, and use `c-x` for "cut" at all times (even when nothing is selected in which case it cuts nothing).

Reason for the question: I have tried `CUA` intermittently for over 2 years and still find it not very useful. The issue is having the same keybinding for entirely different functions depending on whether some text is highlighted, a condition that's quite touchy. I could have highlighted some text but then scrolled to somewhere else in a document and forgot about it, or I could have highlighted something and then lost it accidentally, or I could have mistakenly highlighted something. It could go wrong in many ways, and as fast typers, things will escalate quickly before you realize it.

Answer (score 1):

Using key translations almost works, but it still considers "C-x" a prefix key which makes cutting require C-x and one extra key.

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd  "C-S-x") (kbd "C-x"))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd  "C-x") (kbd "C-w"))
```